# maven dependency not properly compile into war

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using the Eclipse IDE and in the past, I have been developing a maven project depending on local sources (from github (sap-olingo)) as well as maven dependencies loaded as jar. I have now updated the github source and also all the dependencies which seems to break standard eclipse export functionalities (right click porject -> export -> war)

The webproject is working fine when using the maven install functionality and is loading all sources into the META-INF/lib classes, but when using the export as war from eclipse (which I did previously) it is missing to compile a proper dependency. Missing in the sense of that the jar is still present in the META-INF/lib directory of the war, but the content is empty and the size is only 1kb

When comparing the mvn clean install to the exported, there are rarely any differences. Except for the projects that are to be compiled during the runtime. Sizes of the libs in the mvn created war and the exported war roughly matches except for that one jar.

Is there a way to root cause that issue? I am using solely the maven integrated into the IDE which is why I doubt differences in the maven versions and or jdk.
Unfortunately I have no idea in where to start and what info you require

Thanks for your input

**EDIT:**
My projects pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>odata</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
  <name>odataMaven Webapp</name>
  <url></url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.olingo</groupId>
        <artifactId>odata-jpa-processor</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>odata</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${project.build.source}</source>
                    <target>${project.build.source}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.source>1.8</project.build.source>
    </properties>
</project>
```

The odata-jpa-processor source/project is pulled from [here](https://github.com/SAP/olingo-jpa-processor-v4). The problem exists solely with the olingo-jpa-metadata jar which is empty. All other maven dependencies are exported correctly.

Comment: any exceptions ?

Comment: nope, it creates the .war file perfectly without notifying me of anything which is why I do not know where to start investigating

Comment: I suggest you explode the suspicious JAR and decompile the .class files to see their contents.

Comment: So the one from maven build includes the jar as expected and includes the sources as expected from the code. As already said, the other jar is simply empty. It consists of a manifest, only

Comment: Then I don't understand your project's structure. Would you post the directory schema along with their contents?

Comment: I included the github source and the pom  in the original post.